# Real World External CA in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, contract

I want to know that is there any way in which I can use my hardware token containing digital signature (issued by my country CA) to sign a transaction in hyperledger fabric or any other blockchain framework.
I know that there is a concept of external CA in hyperledger fabric but that doesn't apply to a real world CA.

Answer (score 0):

At Hyperledger Fabric, every agent has its own certificates. These certificates are always issued by a CA. So, yo can integrate the certificates issued by your country's CA.

For that, you have to define the corresponding [MSP](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html) instances that you will use. Also, you will require the certificates for each of the agents that you will set up.